How to limit semi-circles on coupon cards
I have a problem when creating a card with a semicircle on each side of its left and right, this semicircle I want to limit to appear only 4, but with background-repeat, it appears infinitely. Can I reduce those half circles?
Expectation:

Reality:


.card-coupon {
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /* border: 1px solid #f5f5f5; */
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    background: radial-gradient(8px at left, #0000 98%, #fff) left,
      radial-gradient(8px at right, #0000 98%, #fff) right;
    background-size: 50.5% 29.2px;
    background-position: top 28.35px left, top 28.35px right;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12));
}

body {
    background: gray;
}
<div class="card-coupon"></div>



So, I want the results to be the same as expected. Thank you :)

Adjust the background-size and background-position values. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gOVWgVN

@Paulie_D I tried it earlier, but the distance between the semicircles is too far.

First, you can use only one gradient for the circles then rely on another gradient to hide the non-needed circle:


.card-coupon {
    --r: 10px; /* control the circle radius */
    --d: 30px; /* control the distance between the cut */
    --h: 45px; /* control what you want to hide */
    --c: #f2f2f2; /* the color */

    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(var(--c) var(--h),#0000 0) 0 calc(var(--h)/-2),   
      radial-gradient(var(--r) at var(--r) 50%, #0000 98%, var(--c))
      calc(-1*var(--r)) 50%/100% var(--d);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12));
}

body {
    background: gray;
}
<div class="card-coupon"></div>



To have exactly 4 you do more calculation:


.card-coupon {
    --r: 10px; /* control the circle radius */
    --d: 30px; /* control the distance between the cut */
    --n: 4;    /* how many you want to show */
    --c: #f2f2f2; /* the color */

    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    --g:/100% calc(50% - var(--n)*var(--d)/2)
       linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) no-repeat;
    background: 
      0 0 var(--g),0 100% var(--g),
      radial-gradient(var(--r) at var(--r) 50%, #0000 98%, var(--c))
      calc(-1*var(--r)) calc(var(--d)/2)/100% var(--d) round;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12));
}

body {
    background: gray;
}
<div class="card-coupon"></div>




I've tried it and it worked, thank you. Something I want to ask, is it possible to use border: 1px solid #F5F5F5 that follows the sides of the circle and card? I've tried it but the result is that the border covers the semi-circle, any suggestions? @TemaniAfif

@BayBay add another drop-shadow: https://jsfiddle.net/Le8vpy5o/1/

ahh, i see, but it won't look like a border style. @TemaniAfif
